# PayumBundle capture payment in background not easy

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

I'm looking simple and correct way to run my process when payment is finish - captured, cancelled.
I think it's a typical requirement.

I don't want to do this in done page - it in my payment method is pending and its user fired. I want when payment gate sends payment finish - background way.

But this is not easy in this bundle.

Events are not fired - so
1 . Add Symfony Events https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/event-dispatcher.md

```
payum.extension.event_dispatcher:
  class: Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Extension\EventDispatcherExtension
  arguments: ["@event_dispatcher"]
  public: true
  tags:
    - { name: payum.extension, all: true, prepend: true }
```

documentation has an error - when prepend is true it works when false - here is my error report

https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/821

I cannot found the correct event name - we have only 3 events

```
const GATEWAY_PRE_EXECUTE = 'payum.gateway.pre_execute';

const GATEWAY_EXECUTE = 'payum.gateway.execute';

const GATEWAY_POST_EXECUTE = 'payum.gateway.post_execute';
```

I add listener PayumEvents::GATEWAY_POST_EXECUTE

I see that almost every operation in this bundle executes some action so before user finish payment my event is fired many times.

in ExecuteEvent I don't know what is happen - i get_class $event->getContext()->getRequest() and have 7 times event fired

```
 Payum\Core\Request\GetHttpRequest
Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\SetExpressCheckout
 Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\GetExpressCheckoutDetails
 Payum\Core\Request\Sync
Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\AuthorizeToken
Payum\Core\Request\Capture
Payum\Core\Request\Capture
```

im just moved to paypal website....

ok i make payment - get next 10 times listener fired ?

```
Payum\Core\Request\GetHttpRequest
Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\GetExpressCheckoutDetails
 Payum\Core\Request\Sync
 Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\DoExpressCheckoutPayment
Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\GetExpressCheckoutDetails
Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\GetTransactionDetails
Payum\Core\Request\Sync
 Payum\Core\Request\Capture
 Payum\Core\Request\Capture
Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Request\Api\GetExpressCheckoutDetails
```

uggh...

please help me - in how I can make a decision when i really get paymentDetails status change.

I just need to fire my process when user paid or cancel payment ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess from the tags of your question that you are using Paypal as payment gateway, in this case, Payum uses by default the done url you have configured, this same url is used as notification url by Paypal, so if there is any status change in your payment, Paypal will call this url again.
So if you need to do something, like dispatching an event, you can do it from here.